# Converting From String To Morse Code in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Unit = Noise | Silent deriving (Eq, Show)

type MorseCode = [Unit]

short, long, smallGap, longGap :: MorseCode
short = [Noise, Silent]
long = [Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent]
smallGap = replicate (3-1) Silent
longGap = replicate (7-1) Silent

morse :: Char -> MorseCode
morse '0' = long ++ long ++ long ++ long ++ long
morse '1' = short ++ long ++ long ++ long ++ long
morse '2' = short ++ short ++ long ++ long ++ long
morse '3' = short ++ short ++ short ++ long ++ long
morse '4' = short ++ short ++ short ++ short ++ long
morse '5' = short ++ short ++ short ++ short ++ short
morse '6' = long ++ short ++ short ++ short ++ short
morse '7' = long ++ long ++ short ++ short ++ short
morse '8' = long ++ long ++ long ++ short ++ short
morse '9' = long ++ long ++ long ++ long ++ short
morse 'A' = short ++ long
morse 'B' = long ++ short ++ short ++ short
morse 'C' = long ++ short ++ long ++ short
morse 'D' = long ++ short ++ short
morse 'E' = short
morse 'F' = short ++ short ++ long ++ short
morse 'G' = long ++ long ++ short
morse 'H' = short ++ short ++ short ++ short
morse 'I' = short ++ short
morse 'J' = short ++ long ++ long ++ long
morse 'K' = long ++ short ++ long
morse 'L' = short ++ long ++ short ++ short
morse 'M' = long ++ long
morse 'N' = long ++ short
morse 'O' = long ++ long ++ long
morse 'P' = short ++ long ++ long ++ short
morse 'Q' = long ++ long ++ short ++ long
morse 'R' = short ++ long ++ short
morse 'S' = short ++ short ++ short
morse 'T' = long
morse 'U' = short ++ short ++ long
morse 'V' = short ++ short ++ short ++ long
morse 'W' = short ++ long ++ long
morse 'X' = long ++ short ++ short ++ long
morse 'Y' = long ++ short ++ long ++ long
morse 'Z' = long ++ long ++ short ++ short
morse _ = undefined -- Avoid warnings

type Table = [(Char, MorseCode)]

morseTable :: Table
morseTable = [ (c , morse c) | c <- ['A'..'Z']++['0'..'9'] ]
```

So I want to create this function

```
convertStringToMorse :: Table -> String -> MorseCode
```

I'm trying to make the function work in a slightly more general way as well, so it works for other types of codes with different tables. Also, I want the output to have a `smallGap` (three `silent`) between each character.

So

```
convertStringToMorse morseTable "SKY" =  [Noise, Silent, Noise, Silent, Noise, Silent, Silent, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent, Noise, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent, Silent, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent, Noise, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent]

convertStringToMorse morseTable "Q" = [Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent, Noise, Silent, Noise, Noise, Noise, Silent]

convertStringToMorse morseTable ""= []
```

I'm not entirely sure where I would start with a function like this in Haskell.

Comment: Have you looked at [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html)? Your table is already a list of pairs, so you could use `fromList` to generate a map. Then your conversion is a lookup that maps over the string. Re: interspersing between each character, you can probably use [`intersperse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`intercalate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) and [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) to accomplish this:

```hs
import Data.List

convertStringToMorse :: [(Char, MorseCode)] -> String -> Maybe MorseCode
convertStringToMorse table str = intercalate [Silent, Silent, Silent]
    <$> mapM (\x -> lookup x table) str
```

The `mapM` is to turn the `[Maybe MorseCode]` into a `Maybe [MorseCode]`, and the `<$>` is to apply the `intercalate` function to the internals of the `Maybe`. See [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) if you're confused about that. If you really need a `MorseCode` and not a `Maybe MorseCode`, you can import `Data.Maybe` and wrap the whole function in [`fromJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust).

Comment: I think the trend now is to use `traverse` instead of `mapM`.